# Get all GET requests to server, or some Laravel GET request log?

Tags: laravel, apache, server, get

I have a Laravel app with Apache2 on Ubuntu server, and I need to get all the GET requests that were sent to this app by time.

Are these requests stored in some log by default, or should I make some logging myself?

Or maybe there is some server history?

I need to get concrete routes and times, like "/edit_user/1, 2018-06-20 08:00:00"

Comment: What have you tried? There is always the apache log if you have enabled it. Also there are a lot of Laravel packages which take care of request logging.

Comment: I've looked only in apache access log, but that's not what I need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the [Apache2 access log](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/logs.html#accesslog). This will contain all requests made to the webserver.

Comment: Yeah, not the access.log itself, but access-myhost.log is just the thing, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You could use a middleware to achieve this.

In app/Http/Kernel.php, add your middleware :

```
/**
 * The application's global HTTP middleware stack.
 *
 * These middleware are run during every request to your application.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $middleware = [
    ...
    \App\Http\Middleware\LogRequest::class
];
```

In app\Http\Middleware\LogRequest.php :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Log;

class LogRequest
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @param  string|null  $guard
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        if ($request->method() === 'GET') {
            Log::notice($request->ip() . ' -> ' ' . $request->path() . ' / ' . now());
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```